# Windbg: Put break-point on all functions in a class

Tags: windbg

I need a simple way of putting break-points on all functions in a class. Something like this `bp myDll!MyClass::*`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this link:

[Windbg by Volker von Einem -> Setting multiple breakpoints via wildcard pattern](http://voneinem-windbg.blogspot.com/2008/01/setting-multiple-breakpoints-via.html)

> Sometimes I need a break point on a specific funtion in multiple classes. Examples are the use of templates, interfaces or inheritence.
>
> This can be easily achived via the bm (I translate as break match).
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> bm /a MyModule!!CComCollectionMap*::*get_Exists*
> ```
>
> This will set a deferred breakpoint on every function that matches the given expression.
>   It is a good idea to check the matches upfront with the following expression:
>
> ```
> x MyModule!!CComCollectionMap*::*get_Exists*
> ```
>
> In order to clear all currently set break points use:
>
> ```
> bc *
> ```

Comment: how can I make this work when a .dll is loaded dynamically? example you can only breakpoint with `bu mymodul!exportedFunction`